# Passing parameters to a dynamically created Button from an Entry widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, dynamic, callback, tkinter

I am looking for a way how to pass the content of a entry widget to a button.
The complicated part for me is that the buttons and entry widgets a dynamically created from a given XML structure see 'xmlString' which is describing a GUI with buttons and parameters, the number of button and parameters is variable.

I simplified  the XML and made a demo code.
I'm aware of the lambda function but I have no idea how to  do this with the dynamic created entry widgets.

```
from Tkinter import *
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


rootframe = Tk()

def runScript(text = 'default text'):
    print 'runScript %s'%text

xmlString = '''
<window>
      <Tab id="tabpage5" name="Debugging" type="custom">
        <command dest="1" mode="CONFIG" unit="4" id="SET_TIMEOUT" type="COMMAND">
          <initiator name="Set Timeout" type="button" />
          <parameter editable="true" param_name="PARAM1">31536000</parameter>
        </command>
        <command dest="1" mode="CONFIG" unit="4" id="SET_thing" type="COMMAND">
          <initiator name="Set Timeout" type="button" />
          <parameter param_name="PARAM1" >31536000</parameter>
          <parameter param_name="PARAM2">5</parameter>
        </command>
        <command />
        </Tab>        
</window>
'''

xmlRoot  = ET.fromstring(xmlString)

for tab in xmlRoot.iter('Tab'):
    row = 0
    column = 0

    for command in tab.iter('command'):
        for tag in command.iter() :
            #not sure why command tag is here but skipping it
            if tag.tag == 'command':
                pass
                continue
            if tag.tag == 'initiator' and tag.attrib['type'] == 'button':
                    button = Button(rootframe, text=tag.attrib['name'], command=lambda : runScript('nondefault text'))
                    button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='w')
                    column +=1
            elif tag.tag == 'parameter':
                    entry = Entry(rootframe)
                    entry.insert(0,tag.text)
                    entry.grid(row=row, column=column)
                    column +=1
        row +=1
        column = 0

rootframe.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a 2D list of all the entries you create. Then when you want to access them, you only need to plug in the row number. Sample implementation:

```
from Tkinter import *
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


rootframe = Tk()

def runScript(text = 'default text', row=None):
    entries = entries_by_row[row] if row is not None else []
    print 'runScript {}. Contents of entries: {}'.format(text, [entry.get() for entry in entries])

xmlString = '''
<window>
      <Tab id="tabpage5" name="Debugging" type="custom">
        <command dest="1" mode="CONFIG" unit="4" id="SET_TIMEOUT" type="COMMAND">
          <initiator name="Set Timeout" type="button" />
          <parameter editable="true" param_name="PARAM1">31536000</parameter>
        </command>
        <command dest="1" mode="CONFIG" unit="4" id="SET_thing" type="COMMAND">
          <initiator name="Set Timeout" type="button" />
          <parameter param_name="PARAM1" >31536000</parameter>
          <parameter param_name="PARAM2">5</parameter>
        </command>
        <command />
        </Tab>        
</window>
'''

xmlRoot  = ET.fromstring(xmlString)

entries_by_row = []

for tab in xmlRoot.iter('Tab'):
    row = 0
    column = 0

    for command in tab.iter('command'):
        entries_by_row.append([])
        for tag in command.iter() :
            #not sure why command tag is here but skipping it
            if tag.tag == 'command':
                pass
                continue
            if tag.tag == 'initiator' and tag.attrib['type'] == 'button':
                    button = Button(rootframe, text=tag.attrib['name'], command=lambda row=row: runScript('nondefault text', row))
                    button.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky='w')
                    column +=1
            elif tag.tag == 'parameter':
                    entry = Entry(rootframe)
                    entry.insert(0,tag.text)
                    entry.grid(row=row, column=column)
                    column +=1
                    entries_by_row[-1].append(entry)
        row +=1
        column = 0

rootframe.mainloop()
```

Result after clicking each button:

```
runScript nondefault text. Contents of entries: ['31536000']
runScript nondefault text. Contents of entries: ['31536000', '5']
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice solution, and one I understood very quick too :)